# Why does recalculating a variable using a Calculate within a single measure return the wrong answer?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to calculate a 12 month trailing sum. When I use CALCULATE to sum account balances over this 12 month period I get different results for when I put in just the variable name as opposed to just adding the code that makes that variable into the Calculate function. I though they should be the same because they are both referring to the same code. Can someone please explain this?

This block returns the undesired value (This is where I'm using the variable name of Sales in the Calculate):

```
TTM Revenue = 

Var Sales = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Fact_FinancialStatement[Period Balance]),
        Dim_FinancialAccounts[UD1] = "Sal"
    )

Var SelectedPeriod = 
    SELECTEDVALUE(Dim_FiscalPeriod[FiscalPeriodIndex])

Var TTM = 
    CALCULATE(
        Sales, 
        ALL(Dim_FiscalPeriod),
        Dim_FiscalPeriod[FiscalPeriodIndex] >= SelectedPeriod - 11 && 
    Dim_FiscalPeriod[FiscalPeriodIndex] <= SelectedPeriod
    )

RETURN
TTM
```

This next block return the desired value but I don't understand why it's different than the first.

```
TTM Revenue = 


Var SelectedPeriod = 
    SELECTEDVALUE(Dim_FiscalPeriod[FiscalPeriodIndex])

Var TTM = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Fact_FinancialStatement[Period Balance]),
        Dim_FinancialAccount[UD1] = "Sal", 
        ALL(Dim_FiscalPeriod),
        Dim_FiscalPeriod[FiscalPeriodIndex] >= SelectedPeriod - 11 &&         
    Dim_FiscalPeriod[FiscalPeriodIndex] <= SelectedPeriod
    )
RETURN
TTM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any data sample provided my answer will be fully theoretical.

In DAX variables are not just 'shortcuts'. You can use them to build your desired calculation logic with proper context.

In your first example Sales are calculated separately from TTM calculation context. The only filter being used there is Dim_FinancialAccounts[UD1]. Then calculation result is placed inside TTM calculation and gets another calculation context for values calculated previously.

In your second example you mix two contexts which have affect combined.